# How to NOT have a responseWrapper in Swagger Codegen Spring server stub

Tags: swagger-codegen

I want Swagger Codegen to generate the Delegate interface without a response wrapper:

Here's what is generated (with irrelevant stuff removed):

```
public interface MyApi {

    MyApiDelegate getDelegate();

    default ResponseEntity<NotificationEntity> httpGetUsingGET(...) {
        ...
    }
```

This is what I'm looking to get generated (note; no `ResponseEntity` wrapper:

```
    default NotificationEntity httpGetUsingGET(...)
```

Here's is the input Swagger Specification

```
'/api/notification/{encryptedId}':
    get:
      tags:
        - Notifications
      summary: Get a specific NotificationModel
      operationId: httpGetUsingGET
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: encryptedId
          in: path
          description: encryptedId
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/NotificationEntity'
```

It's not that I don't like the idea of a response wrapper.   It's that the existing codebase just returns the entities without a wrapper.

I'm using SwaggerHub to generate this and leaving the `responseWrapper` configuration for Spring Server Stub blank.   But I suspect a default is being applied.   I looked through the Swagger Codegen sources and couldn't find a way to specify "NONE".